# Permit my app to be used free for limited number of days

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement the feature in my app that will permit user to use my application free only for few days and after that i will alert the user to buy this app through IAP .
e.g. when i install some trail version software on windows it has evaluation period of somedays and after expiry of trial period it asks to buy for this software every time i install a fresh copy that software need to implement something like this.
googled a lot about this issue but nothing working for me and i also dont know from where to start.
so please can any body help me on this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**App Store Rejects on 2.9: Apps that are “beta”, “demo”, “trial”, or “test” versions will be rejected**

This Guideline says you can not tried this type of feature in your app.
but you implement this type of feature in your app and submit app to app store your app will rejected by apple.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the App Store Review Board doesn't like trial versions of apps. I haven't tried making a trial version, but doing this will probably get your app rejected.

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> **2.9**
>   Apps that are "beta", "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected.

However, in some cases you can use subscriptions to provide content. See [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865658/in-app-purchases-and-trial-runs) for more about that.